# How to block Criteo popups ads?

Tags: applications, samsung, 7.0-nougat, ads, popup

I have a samsung s6 with android 7.0 and recently I have get some popup ads showing up in full screen mode when entering an app on my phone.
I tried to delete recently installed apps but the problem didn't go away.
I also tried adguard, malwarbytes and avast , adblock but none of them solved the problem.
When I enter the app info it says it is from Criteo.

I tried to block the ads from chrome browser and from google settings there is no way to disable those ads.

Can someone please help as I was not having this issue in the past.
I am open for any suggestion
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you caught a good one. Use s file explorer and search your stystem for a package named: com.criteo.events. This company is also pretty good at hiding themselves and on some projects regenerating them selves. Not only do they send unwanted advertisements they also collect target user information. I would flash factory firmware with odin I would reset your Google advertising Id too. These guys will also try to target other devices connected to your e-mail account. I noticed this comment from their git:  "Set the email address of the user that can be then used for cross device retargeting."

Comment: @BoLawson I used my phone file explorer but also from the computer to look inside Phone\Android\data but couldn't find criteo there :( Is there anywhere I can know which package should be deleted there that could be associated with criteo. thaanks

Comment: The wrapper default location and it will not be in the area's that certain files are supposed to go. The absolute path is not documented in the source code. In fact it takes steps to mask/hide its location setting up symlinks so that its absolute path is not discovered. Its not an apk but a script that starts Gradle build which represents one or more projects. A project represents a library JAR or a web application or it might represent a ZIP that assembled from the JARs produced by other projects. How are you with a shell command line? Its not impossible to trace it but extremely difficult

Comment: It would be easier just to flash a official factory firmware through odin. Destroy the environment a start over so to speak. Its crazy I have Never actually seen one of these in a real world device. Here is documentation on the gradle wrapper to give you an idea of what this is: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_build_script.htm

Comment: @BoLawson I'm a software developer but not in mobile or web app. So I would go with the first option since I don't want to loose my data. I'm also interested in finding it out LOL , Only if this malware was in my windows 7 I would track it :p I've never formatted my laptop since 2014 :D for shell I'm ok with it since I used bash from linux in the past . thanks for your precious help